# how to put "case" into loop

Tags: java, loops, combobox, case

Here is fragment code of my program that will simulate Solar System. Depending on what user will write in "amountField", "Number" of planets will change, and so will ComboBox "listOfPlanet". And here is my problem. I found out how to "resize" Combobox but i have no idea how to make case "X" depend on "Number". As u see i had to manually write 12 cases.

```
amountField = new JTextField(6);
        ActionListener amountListener = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String amountData = amountField.getText();
                    Number = Integer.parseInt(amountData);
                    listOfPlanet.removeAllItems();
                    for(int i = 0; i<Number; i++) {
                        listOfPlanet.addItem("Planeta" + i);
                    }
                    b = new Ball(leftMainPanel);
                }
            };
            amountField.addActionListener(amountListener);
        rightUpPanel.add(amountField);


    listOfPlanet = new JComboBox();

    for(int i = 0; i<Number; i++) {
        listOfPlanet.addItem("Planeta" + i);
    }

    ActionListener ComboListener = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int temp;
                temp = listOfPlanet.getSelectedIndex();
                    switch(temp){
                    case 0: 
                        iii=0;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        iii=1;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        iii=2;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        iii=3;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        iii=4;
                        break;
                    case 5: 
                        iii=5;
                        break;
                    case 6: 
                        iii=6;
                        break;
                    case 7: 
                        iii=7;
                        break;
                    case 8: 
                        iii=8;
                        break;
                    case 9: 
                        iii=9;
                        break;
                    case 10: 
                        iii=10;
                        break;
                    case 11: 
                        iii=11;
                        break;
                    case 12: 
                        iii=12;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            };

        listOfPlanet.addActionListener(ComboListener);
```

is there any way to make it work like this? :

```
for(int i=0; i<Number; i++) {
     case i: 
     iii=i;
     break;
}
```

Comment: Yes, there is a way, simply put it in the superloop where you want it to be.

Comment: I don't know what to say, stumped, my gaster is beyond flabbered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
iii = listOfPlanet.getSelectedIndex();
```

Does that not work? You should get iii = to the index of whichever planet is selected from the dropdown box.

Comment: Holy *** It works haha :D It's so funny i was so blind. Thanks!